# Remove empty rows from Grid layout in WP7 C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, grid

I created Grid layout with 'n' number of rows and columns programmatically like this.

```
Grid test = new Grid();
for (int i = 1; i <= cols1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= rows1; j++)
    {
        if (array[i, j] != null)
        {
            ColumnDefinition col = new ColumnDefinition();
            col.Width = new GridLength(50);
            test.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);
            RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
            row.Height = new GridLength(50);
            test.RowDefinitions.Add(row);

            Image img = new Image();
            img.source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("testimg.jpg", urikind.Relative));
            Grid.SetRow(img, j);
            Grid.SetColumn(img, i);
            test.Children.Add(img);
        }
    }
}
```

the null values are not added in grid. so that there is empty columns. it makes space in the empty columns.
How to avoid the empty column.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the result you have and how would you like it to be?

Comment: you sould do something like this: `else{ j--; }`

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml If the i'th 5th value is null then the grid leaves the 5 th column. i cant remove the 5 th column that is the empty column. if i use testgrid.ColumnDefinitions.RemoveAt(5); it throws an error like Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. please help

Comment: 5th is 4 actually 0=1st 1=2nd 2=3rd 3=4th 4=5th elements

Comment: What this means to you?: `the grid leaves the 5 th column`

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml From 1 to 4 there have a value and 5 is null and then after 6 it has values means the 5 th column is blank that is a space between the columns. how to remove that empty column.

Comment: There is nothing in the 5th column for every row or just for some ?

Comment: This is what you have http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmxuf.png how would you like to see it?

Comment: yes instead of text, i have images in that columns. if the total column is empty how to remove the empty column. because that empty column makes many spaces.

Comment: you do i-- but you must switch your for cycles

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
Grid test = new Grid();
for (int j = 0; j <= rows1; j++)
{ 
    RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
    row.Height = new GridLength(50);
    test.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
    for (int i = 0; i <= cols1; i++)
    {
        if (array[i, j] != null)
        {
            if(j == 0)
            { 
                ColumnDefinition col = new ColumnDefinition();
                col.Width = new GridLength(50);
                test.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);
            }
            Image img = new Image();
            img.source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("testimg.jpg", urikind.Relative));
            Grid.SetRow(img, j);
            Grid.SetColumn(img, i);
            test.Children.Add(img);
        }
        else
        {
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

### Note:

You should avoid to add `ColumnDefinition` and `RowDefinition` for each element.
You should add `ColumnDefinition` **one** every **column** and `RowDefinition` **one** every **row**.

Comment: yes i did like this, if i add the column at 1 st and then 7 th means it creates a space between they. so have to fix scrollviewer to see the last position. it makes the design ugly

Comment: i dint add column for the null values but there is a space in the grid, in that null value columns.

Answer (score 0):

Set MaxWidth of empty ColumnDefinition/RowDefinition to 0.